# if \ else vs. switch \ case в C#

Tags: c#

Что лучше использовать: if\else или switch\case?

```
int a = 3;

if (a == 1)
{
    ...
}
else if (a == 2)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}

switch(a)
{
    case 1:
        ...
        break;

    case 2:
        ...
        break;

    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

- Какая из этих конструкций работает быстрее? Почему?
- Когда лучше использовать то или другое?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Оба условных оператора работают с одинаковой скоростью. Так как на уровне машинных команд они преобразуются в одни и те же инструкции.

Выбирать имеет смысл только по вкусу и по задаче.

`switch` может работать только с одной переменной. У `if` таких ограничений нет.

На мой взгляд, язык C# слишком высокоуровневый для такого рода оптимизаций.

Пишите читаемый код ;)

Comment: Дополню: если в switch много условий, то используется [Dictionary](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/07/csharp-switch-statements-are-hashed/)

Answer (score 23):

Ответ выше не совсем корректный, даже учитывая комментарий.

Если значения лежат рядом, например:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0: /* */ break;
    case 1: /* */ break;
    case 2: /* */ break;
    case 3: /* */ break;
    case 4: /* */ break;
    case 5: /* */ break;
}
```

В таком случае компилятор генерирует таблицу переходов (jump table) (IL-код):

```
switch (IL_0043, IL_004e, IL_0059, IL_0064, IL_006f, IL_007a)
```

Время работы такой таблицы `O(1)`. Не нужно волноваться, если несколько значений упущено, и они не идут один за другим, в таком случае компилятор все равно генерирует таблицу переходов:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0: /* */ break;
    case 1: /* */ break;
    case 2: /* */ break;
    case 3: /* */ break;
    case 4: /* */ break;
    case 5: /* */ break;
    case 9: /* */ break;
    case 13: /* */ break;
}
```

IL:

```
switch (IL_0043, IL_004e, IL_0059, IL_0064, IL_006f, IL_007a, IL_009a, IL_009a, IL_009a, IL_0085, IL_009a, IL_009a, IL_009a, IL_0090)
```

Как видно, "дырки" заполнились переходами за конец конструкции `switch`: `IL_009a`

Если расстояние между значениями слишком большое для построение одной таблицы, компилятор может разделить их на 2+ таблицы. Например:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0: /* */ break;
    case 1: /* */ break;
    case 2: /* */ break;
    case 3: /* */ break;
    case 2000000000: /* */ break;
    case 2000000001: /* */ break;
    case 2000000002: /* */ break;
    case 2000000003: /* */ break;
    case 2000000004: /* */ break;
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0004: ldloc.0
IL_0005: switch (IL_0037, IL_0042, IL_004d, IL_0058)

IL_001a: ldloc.0
IL_001b: ldc.i4 2000000000
IL_0020: sub
IL_0021: switch (IL_0063, IL_006e, IL_0079, IL_0084)
```

Как видно из примера выше, компилятор выделил 2 таблицы переходов. Для другой таблицы из значения вычитается `2,000,000,000`. В общем случае скорость выполнения `O(1)` или `O(m)`, где m - количество групп.

Посмотрим что будет в общем случае. Я взял 20 случайных чисел:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 955626049: /* */ break;
    case 1732096473: /* */ break;
    case 1416261125: /* */ break;
    case 901627868: /* */ break;
    case 713886433: /* */ break;
    case 289231272: /* */ break;
    case 598309392: /* */ break;
    case 1284278823: /* */ break;
    case 1517161566: /* */ break;
    case 1548994144: /* */ break;
    case 1854092737: /* */ break;
    case 1725885116: /* */ break;
    case 1984539276: /* */ break;
    case 558794563: /* */ break;
    case 337975821: /* */ break;
    case 1687544575: /* */ break;
    case 1048183578: /* */ break;
    case 102389471: /* */ break;
    case 1017837673: /* */ break;
    case 1012360293: /* */ break;
}
```

В таком случае компилятор их сортирует, и ищет бинарным поиском:

```
IL_0004: ldloc.0
IL_0005: ldc.i4 1017837673
IL_000a: bgt IL_0099

IL_000f: ldloc.0
IL_0010: ldc.i4 598309392
IL_0015: bgt.s IL_0058

IL_0017: ldloc.0
IL_0018: ldc.i4 289231272
IL_001d: bgt.s IL_0036

IL_001f: ldloc.0
IL_0020: ldc.i4 102389471
IL_0025: beq IL_016e

IL_002a: ldloc.0
IL_002b: ldc.i4 289231272
IL_0030: beq IL_0126

IL_0035: ret

IL_0036: ldloc.0
IL_0037: ldc.i4 337975821
IL_003c: beq IL_015c

IL_0041: ldloc.0
IL_0042: ldc.i4 558794563
IL_0047: beq IL_0156

IL_004c: ldloc.0
IL_004d: ldc.i4 598309392
IL_0052: beq IL_012c

IL_0057: ret

IL_0058: ldloc.0
IL_0059: ldc.i4 901627868
IL_005e: bgt.s IL_0077

IL_0060: ldloc.0
IL_0061: ldc.i4 713886433
IL_0066: beq IL_0120

IL_006b: ldloc.0
IL_006c: ldc.i4 901627868
IL_0071: beq IL_011a

IL_0076: ret

IL_0077: ldloc.0
IL_0078: ldc.i4 955626049
IL_007d: beq IL_0108

IL_0082: ldloc.0
IL_0083: ldc.i4 1012360293
IL_0088: beq IL_017a

IL_008d: ldloc.0
IL_008e: ldc.i4 1017837673
IL_0093: beq IL_0174

IL_0098: ret

IL_0099: ldloc.0
IL_009a: ldc.i4 1548994144
IL_009f: bgt.s IL_00d6

IL_00a1: ldloc.0
IL_00a2: ldc.i4 1284278823
IL_00a7: bgt.s IL_00bd

IL_00a9: ldloc.0
IL_00aa: ldc.i4 1048183578
IL_00af: beq IL_0168

IL_00b4: ldloc.0
IL_00b5: ldc.i4 1284278823
IL_00ba: beq.s IL_0132

IL_00bc: ret

IL_00bd: ldloc.0
IL_00be: ldc.i4 1416261125
IL_00c3: beq.s IL_0114

IL_00c5: ldloc.0
IL_00c6: ldc.i4 1517161566
IL_00cb: beq.s IL_0138

IL_00cd: ldloc.0
IL_00ce: ldc.i4 1548994144
IL_00d3: beq.s IL_013e

IL_00d5: ret

IL_00d6: ldloc.0
IL_00d7: ldc.i4 1725885116
IL_00dc: bgt.s IL_00ef

IL_00de: ldloc.0
IL_00df: ldc.i4 1687544575
IL_00e4: beq.s IL_0162

IL_00e6: ldloc.0
IL_00e7: ldc.i4 1725885116
IL_00ec: beq.s IL_014a

IL_00ee: ret

IL_00ef: ldloc.0
IL_00f0: ldc.i4 1732096473
IL_00f5: beq.s IL_010e

IL_00f7: ldloc.0
IL_00f8: ldc.i4 1854092737
IL_00fd: beq.s IL_0144

IL_00ff: ldloc.0
IL_0100: ldc.i4 1984539276
IL_0105: beq.s IL_0150

IL_0107: ret
```

В таком случае скорость выполнения будет `O(log n)`.

Аналогичная `if then else` конструкция выполняется за `O(n)`. А это значит `switch` почти всегда быстрее `if then else`.

Все примеры IL скомпилированы для .NET версии 4.6

**Дополнение для `String`:**

Для типа `string` работает немного по-другому, так как таблицу переходов не построить, а искать бинарным поиском (перебирая каждый символ) - неоптимально. В таком компилятор считает хеш всех строк, а потом во время выполнения считает хеш от входящей строки, и ищет бинарным поиском. Пример:

```
switch (x)
{
    case "ff": return 10;
    case "f1": return 11;
    case "f2": return 12;
    case "f3": return 13;
    case "f4": return 14;
    case "f5": return 15;
    case "f6": return 16;
    case "f7": return 17;
    case "f8": return 18;
    case "f9": return 19;
    case "10": return 20;
    case "11": return 21;
    case "12": return 22;
    default:
        return 0;
}
```

IL-код:

```
IL_0001: call uint32 '<PrivateImplementationDetails>'::ComputeStringHash(string)
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldc.i4 89242279
IL_000d: bgt.un.s IL_0063

IL_000f: ldloc.0
IL_0010: ldc.i4 38909422
IL_0015: bgt.un.s IL_003d

IL_0017: ldloc.0
IL_0018: ldc.i4 5354184
IL_001d: beq IL_0147

IL_0022: ldloc.0
IL_0023: ldc.i4 22131803
IL_0028: beq IL_0159

IL_002d: ldloc.0
IL_002e: ldc.i4 38909422
IL_0033: beq IL_011d

IL_0038: br IL_01da

IL_003d: ldloc.0
IL_003e: ldc.i4 55687041
IL_0043: beq IL_0132

IL_0048: ldloc.0
IL_0049: ldc.i4 72464660
IL_004e: beq IL_00f3

IL_0053: ldloc.0
IL_0054: ldc.i4 89242279
IL_0059: beq IL_0108

IL_005e: br IL_01da

IL_0063: ldloc.0
IL_0064: ldc.i4 1972548895
IL_0069: bgt.un.s IL_008b

IL_006b: ldloc.0
IL_006c: ldc.i4 122797517
IL_0071: beq.s IL_00de

IL_0073: ldloc.0
IL_0074: ldc.i4 810679896
IL_0079: beq.s IL_00c9

IL_007b: ldloc.0
IL_007c: ldc.i4 1972548895
IL_0081: beq IL_01a4

IL_0086: br IL_01da

IL_008b: ldloc.0
IL_008c: ldc.i4 2006104133
IL_0091: bgt.un.s IL_00ae

IL_0093: ldloc.0
IL_0094: ldc.i4 1989326514
IL_0099: beq IL_0195

IL_009e: ldloc.0
IL_009f: ldc.i4 2006104133
IL_00a4: beq IL_0186

IL_00a9: br IL_01da

IL_00ae: ldloc.0
IL_00af: ldc.i4 -28201054
IL_00b4: beq IL_0168

IL_00b9: ldloc.0
IL_00ba: ldc.i4 -11423435
IL_00bf: beq IL_0177

IL_00c4: br IL_01da
```

После этого идет сравнение методом System.String::op_Equality (так как хеш может совпать и у разных строк). Этот механизм не является хеш-таблицей, так как в хеш-таблицы скорость доступа к элементу `O(1)`, а здесь просто бинарный поиск за `O(log n)`

Я попытался создать очень большой `switch` на 60 строк, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что и это не полный ответ, так как у компилятора есть много различных оптимизаций для `switch-case` и `if-else`. И в случае такого выбора: `case "Hello": return 1;` вместо меток перехода может быть использована коллекция `Dictionary<string, int>`. Наверняка, с приходом паттерн-матчинга будет добавлено ещё множество оптимизаций, которые сделают поведение `switch-case` ещё менее предсказуемым.

Comment: Вы не правы. Добавил информацию про `string`

Comment: А почему вы смотрите в IL, а не в генерируемый после JIT машинный код? Основная часть оптимизаций происходит именно там.

Comment: Компилятор c# раскручивает `switch` до уже достаточно простых инструкций. Если в IL коде генерируется бинарный поиск за `O(log n)`, но оптимизатор JIT ну никак не оптимизирует его до `O(1)`.

Comment: @Zergatul: Но он может соптимизировать цепочку ифов.

Comment: @Zergatul всё верно для .NET Framework. А вот компиляция в Mono выдаёт решение с Dictionary, и это понятно, так как логика при работе с ним точно такая же, как описали вы. Поиск по хэшу, затем точное сравнение. Я лишь хотел обратить внимание, что это детали реализации, которые могут меняться в зависимости от типа, количества кейсов, переходов между метками и версии компилятора.

Comment: @LunarWhisper несомненно, они могут меняться, но основная идея в том, что компилятор очень хорошо оптимизирует `switch`, и не стоит боятся его использовать. Если что-то и будут менять, то точно не в худшую сторону.

Answer (score 3):

Вы задаётесь неправильным вопросом.

Если ваша задача — ускорить вашу программу, то решением этой задачи никогда не будет «заменить свитч на последовательность ифов» или наоборот. Ускорение программы проводится на уровне используемых алгоритмов и структур данных.

Тот факт, что один или другой вариант в тех или иных условиях, на той или иной версии компилятора выполняется на несколько наносекунд быстрее, не стоит потраченных на него байт текста.

Во-первых, вы должны помнить, что ваша главная задача — не выиграть 10 тактов процессора (несчастное переключение контекста стоит намного больше!), а сделать вашу программу понятной. Поэтому вы должны использовать `switch` там, где это прибавляет читаемости коду, там, где это соответствует тому, что именно вы хотите сказать этим кодом. И использовать `if` там, где это лучше отражает вашу мысль.

Например, если вы устраиваете перебор значений `enum`'а, то чаще всего вам нужен `switch`. А если вы реально проверяете несколько условий, особенно с длинными вычислениями, то, возможно, лучше цепочка `if`'ов.

Ну и во-вторых, то, что на одной версии компилятора один из методов выражения одной и той же идеи компилируется в более быстрый код, чем другой метод — штука временная и преходящая. Помните, что в C++ сначала рекомендовалось возвращать значения по ссылке для скорости, а затем пришёл тренд «[want speed? pass by value!](https://web.archive.org/web/20140116234633/http://cpp-next.com:80/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)», и наверняка это поменялось сейчас ещё раз.

Поскольку код имеет одинаковый смысл, то в любом из его вариантов рано или поздно он будет компилироваться в одно и то же. JIT-компилятор C# *покамест* не генерирует одинаковый объектный код для этих двух случаев, а вот компиляторы C++ [уже умеют](https://godbolt.org/g/LqLWB5).

Итак, то, какая из имплементаций скорее, а какая медленнее — это не абсолютное понятие.

---

Вы не должны жертвовать читаемостью кода ради сиюминутной мизерной выгоды. Пишите не «как скорее», а «как правильнее». Расходы на поддержку плохо написанного кода несравнимо больше выгод от микрооптимизаций.

Comment: Это правильно, но все же может стоит упомянуть, что в случае цепочки `if`-ов и если логика чтения кода в соответствии с алгоритмом не страдает и вы знаете, что *некоторые условия более вероятны*, то следует вытаскивать их к началу цепочки.

Comment: @avp: В ассемблерном листинге, который я привёл, видно, что этим занимается сам компилятор. Поэтому лучше дать хинты для компилятора, или использовать profile-guided optimization (особенно удобно это делать как раз JIT-компилятору!)